# Which type of solid wood flooring would be most scratch resistant?

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, wood-finish

My research so far indicates that lacquered floors are most maintenance free. Meanwhile simple brushed finish will need occasional 'top-up' with oils.
I'm not aware of what other finishes are available there, but I would like to know which would last better against scratches, specifically from pets.

Comment: Investigate the Janka Scale or Janka rating for finding the hardest wood for flooring (https://www.builddirect.com/learning-center/flooring/janka-hardness-rating-scale/). Bamboo is at the top.  Your title seems to be asking about species of wood while your body seems focused on finishes.

Comment: Does it mean the finish has nothing to do how easily will the product scratch? I'm talking here about surface scratches onlyl

Comment: The finishes you apply certainly have varying degrees of scratch resistance but the hardness of the wood affects the performance greatly. A very durable polyurethane will not make a balsa wood floor scratch resistant because the fibers of the wood are so soft it allows the finish to break like ice on a pond. Yet that same poly coating would be very durable on top of oak or Brazilian cherry.